# hide div tag where id with jquery and mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to hide div where id with jquery and mvc?

```
<div class="List-Display">
    @for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        <div  id="@i">
            <span>content</span>
        </div>
        <button onclick="display(@i)" type="button">
    }
 </div>
```

I've tried the following but not worked!

```
<script>
    function display(parameters) {
        $('.List-Display').find('div[id!=' + parameters + ']').hide();
        //or
            $('.List-Display').filter('div[id!=' + parameters + ']').hide();
        }
    </script>
```

I need to hide div tag where `id!=parameters`. But I have no idea!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use :

```
$('.List-Display').children('div:not("#' + parameters + '")').hide();
```

. its worked;

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.List-Display').find('div:not("#'+ parameters + '")').hide();
```

Comment: @john: Please try again. I had written the code as per your earlier HTML markup... [`Fiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Pyn/)